# Function is declared, but not defined in shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a source code of some library. There is a function that is only declared (in a header file), but not defined in the source code.

```
extern "C"  {
    extern int theFunc(int);
}
```

What is the reason to have only a declaration of a function in a library?

Comment: Generally, there is none. Maybe there is one but that would need the context.

Comment: _What is the reason to have only a declaration of a function in a library?_ This is sometimes what I do to define an API. (I prototype all functions which should be part of the API by design.) These API might be for an internally used library which is part of a current project but I see it's potential use for other applications too. As my boss is permanently asking for when the application is ready, I use a typical comp.science trick: [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), i.e. I implement everything what's immediately needed (and ignore the rest for now).

Comment: As long as the prototyped function is not called (nor it's function pointer is used), it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of [Mike Kinghan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188395/841108) (which covers most of the cases), there is also a (rather unusual) reason to declare in the library header file a function not implemented in that library. Sometimes, that library expects a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) and the user is expected to provide such a plugin (in some way, perhaps passing the plugin file name to some other function). The library would use [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) techniques (such as [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on Linux) to install such a plugin. And it would fetch some *particular* function  (with [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) on Linux) from the plugin. Then it makes sense to *declare*, but not *define* such a plugin function, in the library headers.

I do admit that this case is unusual and contrived.

For a concrete example, read about [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). Your plugin should `#include "gcc-plugin.h"` which *indirectly* declares

```
/* Declaration for "plugin_init" function so that it doesn't need to be
   duplicated in every plugin.  */
extern int plugin_init (struct plugin_name_args *plugin_info,
                        struct plugin_gcc_version *version);
```

but that `plugin_init` should be *defined* by your plugin code. Then GCC would `dlopen` your plugin, using something equivalent to

```
void*plhdl = dlopen("/home/you/yourplugin.so", RTLD_NOW);
```

and later get a function pointer using

```
typeof(plugin_init)* funptr = dlsym(plhdl, "plugin_init");
```

Notice that the *symbol* `plugin_init` does *not* appear in the code segment of GCC.

Another example is the Qt framework (a set of libraries). Read about [Qt plugins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html).

Comment: This assumes that the symbol plugin_init is referenced in the library, right? Otherwise it would not be exported from the library.

Comment: No, the library would do a `dlsym`

Comment: "maybe", "could", answer a too broad/unclear question is really not a good thing, you encourage people to make bad question. (even if your answer is not wrong)